# Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope

Tags: http, soap, soapui, soap-client

I had constructed a soap over http protocol request message as following:

```
<HttpClientRq>
            <header>
                <parameter name="Content-Type" value="text/xml"/>
            </header>
            <body>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.soapui.org/sample/">
                     <soapenv:Header/>
                     <soapenv:Body>
                     <sam:login>
                     <username>Login</username>
                     <password>Login123</password>
                     </sam:login>
                     </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </body>
        </HttpClientRq>
```

I use SOAPUI tool create a mock services operation, login.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.soapui.org/sample/">
                     <soapenv:Header/>
                     <soapenv:Body>
                     <sam:login>
                     <username>Login</username>
                     <password>Login123</password>
                     </sam:login>
                     </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I send the request message above, SOAPUI manages to receive the request message successfully. But unfortunately, it hits an error shown as below:

```
ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope, expecting [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]], see error log for details
2016-07-26 17:31:57,943 ERROR [errorlog] com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope, expecting [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope, expecting [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:241)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:113)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.dispatchRequest(WsdlMockRunner.java:142)
    at com.eviware.soapui.monitor.JettyMockEngine$ServerHandler.handle(JettyMockEngine.java:604)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:945)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: Missing/Invalid SOAP Envelope, expecting [{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope]
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapUtils.getBodyElement(SoapUtils.java:134)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapUtils.getContentElement(SoapUtils.java:172)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.soap.SoapUtils.findOperationForRequest(SoapUtils.java:200)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockDispatcher.dispatchPostRequest(WsdlMockDispatcher.java:191)
    ... 15 more
```

I don't understand. The error log complains invalid/missing soap:envelope although I had included within my request message.
I hope someone can provide me advice and guidance, appreciate so much.

Comment: were you able to solve this?